# I am unable to delete messages left on my homepage to delete from my messages db and the homepage itself

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to delete messages from a home page I have and when I press the delete button I get some php error messages saying my declared fields are all invalid, as well as a database error - Unknown column ' = 'message'' in 'where clause'. I'm trying to delete the message not only from the homepage but from the database too. I have clearly stated the from, to and message fields in my messagesTable array, so why are they saying invalid? My function is called `delete($messageTable)`.

My model:

```
class Messages extends CI_Model
{

   private $messagesTable = 'messages'; 

   function Messages()
   {
      parent::__construct();
   }


   function addMessage($from, $to, $message)
   {
      $record = array(
        'to' => $to,
        'from' => $from,
        'message' => $message);
      $this->db->insert('messages', $record);   
   }


   function getMessages($user)
   {

      $this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->from('messages');
      //$this->db->where('to', $user);
      $messagesSet = $this->db->get();

      $messages = array ();

      foreach ($messagesSet->result() as $row)
      {
      $messages[] = array('from' => $row->from, 'message' => $row->message);

      } 

      return $messages;
   }


   function delete($messagesTable) {

      $messagesTable = array(
        $from  => 'from',
        $to  => 'to',
        $message => 'message');

          $this->db->select('*')->from('messages')->where($messagesTable);
          $this->db->delete($messagesTable);
    }
```

}

My view:

```
 <div id="maincontent">
  <div id="primary">     
    <h2> Friends </h2> 
    <ul> 
       <?php foreach ($friends['mutual'] as $name):?>
       <li> 
       <?=anchor("profile/view/$name", $name)?>, (<?=anchor("home/drop/$name", 'drop')?>)
       </li>
        <?php endforeach?>
     </ul>
   <h2> Following </h2> 
    <ul>
      <?php foreach($friends['following'] as $name):?>
        <li>  <?=anchor("profile/view/$name", $name)?>, (<?=anchor("home/drop/$name", 'drop')?>)</li>
      <?php endforeach?>
    </ul>
    <h2> Followers </h2> 
    <ul>
     <?php foreach($friends ['followers'] as $name):?>
        <li>
          <?=anchor("profile/view/$name", $name)?>
        </li>
      <?php endforeach?>
    </ul>
  </div>  
  <div id="secondary">
    <h2> Messages</h2> 
    <ul> 
      <?php foreach($messages as $message):?>
          <li><?=$message['from']?> says...: "<?=$message['message']?>"(<?=anchor("home/delete/{$message['from']}", 'delete')?>)</li>      
         <?php endforeach?>    
    </ul>      
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
 class Home extends CI_Controller 
 {
 function Home()
 {
 parent::__construct();
 $this->load->model('messages');
 $this->load->model('friends');
 $this->load->model("profiles");


 }

   function drop($member)
  {
   $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
   $this->friends->deleteFriend($username, $member);
   redirect('home');
  }



   function delete($messagesTable) {

$this->messages->delete($messagesTable);
$this->index();

    }


function index()
{

 $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
 $membername = $this->session->userdata('membername');
 $viewData['membername'] = $membername;
 $viewData['username'] = $username;
 $viewData['following'] = $this->friends->getFollowing($username);
 $viewData['followers'] = $this->friends->getFollowers($username);
 $viewData['messages'] = $this->messages->getMessages($membername);
 $viewData['friends'] = $this->friends->getFriends($username);


 $this->load->view('shared/header');
 $this->load->view('home/hometitle', $viewData);
 $this->load->view('shared/nav');
 $this->load->view('home/homeview', $viewData);
 $this->load->view('shared/footer');
}

  }
```

Comment: Please improve your question, see my comment in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13674489/why-cantt-i-delete-a-message-from-my-database-and-have-it-take-affect-on-the-sc)

Comment: I have a delete anchor that is meant to delete a specific message placed previously in the messages database by a friend. How can i amend my code so that the message will disappear from the screen and the database - let me know if thats not clear

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: from

Filename: models/messages.php

Line Number: 51

Comment: A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this

```
$messagesTable = array(
    $from  => 'from',
    $to  => 'to',
    $message => 'message');
```

Be

```
$messagesTable = array(
    'from'  => $from,
    'to'  => $to,
    'message' => $message);
```

??

Comment: Yes Ive tried this but I keep getting invalid variable errors for all 3 of the variables inside the array. But now I'm getting a different database error that refers to another similar delete function I had -You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM (`friends`) WHERE `username` = 'homer'' at line 1

SELECT *, * FROM (`friends`) WHERE `username` = 'homer' - this sql command deletes a user from my membership database.

Comment: Here is that function I'm referring to to stop any confusion :            function deleteUser($username)
  
  {
   $deleteMember = $this->db->select('*')->from('membership')->where('username', $username);
   $delete = $this->db->delete('membership', $deleteMember);
   
  }

Comment: Well, you should var_dump($deleteMember); to make sure that the returned data is what you're looking for

Comment: no see believe it or not $deleteMember actually works the database error is simply referring to this function because it doesnt seem to like the look of this, which is actually what i'm trying to get working:

Comment: function delete($messagesTable) {
  
  $messagesTable = array(
    'from'  => $from,
            'to'  => $to,
       'message' => $message);
  
       $this->db->select('*')->from('messages')->where($messagesTable);
       $this->db->delete('messages', $messagesTable);
      


    }